# while using multiple in getting error in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT  em.Ename 
FROM    dbo.Email_tbl e 
JOIN dbo.EmployeeMaster_tbl em ON em.Ecode = e.ECode
WHERE e.plcid='25'
```

which gives me an output like this:

```
Ename
-------------------
Ahmed
Ahmed Elkhouli
akbar
Alaudddin
```

I have another query like this:

```
SELECT e.Ename 
from dbo.EmployeeMaster_tbl e 
WHERE e.gid not IN(SELECT did 
                   FROM dbo.Designation_tbl d 
                   WHERE d.Dname ='Driver'  )
```

And I am getting output like this:

```
Ename
--------------------------------------------------
Shaijomon John
Masum
Tausef Ahmad
Abdu Rahiman
Mohammad Shopan
Benzy P A
Mohammad Ali
Kauser Mohammad
Rasheed Pulakkuttathil
Lakshuman Perappan
Ahmed
Ahmed Elkhouli
akbar
Alaudddin
```

I need to output ename for rows that are not present in the first query.

so I tried query like this:

```
SELECT e.Ename 
from dbo.EmployeeMaster_tbl e 
WHERE e.gid not IN(SELECT did 
                   FROM dbo.Designation_tbl d 
                   WHERE d.Dname ='Driver') 
and not in (SELECT  em.Ename 
            FROM  dbo.Email_tbl e 
            JOIN dbo.EmployeeMaster_tbl em ON em.Ecode = e.ECode 
            WHERE e.plcid='25')
order by e.Ename
```

but I am getting an Incorrect syntax error near the keyword `in`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e.Ename from dbo.EmployeeMaster_tbl e 
WHERE e.gid not IN 
(SELECT did 
FROM dbo.Designation_tbl d
 WHERE d.Dname ='Driver') 
 and e.name not in (SELECT  em.Ename 
 FROM  dbo.Email_tbl e 
JOIN dbo.EmployeeMaster_tbl em 
ON em.Ecode = e.ECode 
WHERE e.plcid='25')
order by e.Ename
```

Comment: that would be yes ma'am.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You are missing `e.Ename` in where condition

```
SELECT e.Ename from dbo.EmployeeMaster_tbl e 
 WHERE e.gid not IN(SELECT did FROM dbo.Designation_tbl d WHERE d.Dname ='Driver') 
 and e.Ename not in (SELECT  em.Ename FROM  dbo.Email_tbl e 
 JOIN dbo.EmployeeMaster_tbl em ON em.Ecode = e.ECode WHERE e.plcid='25')
 order by e.Ename
```